# How to rotate a curve to show on a different axis?

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

When I create a NURBS Curve, It only shows on the Z Axis:

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to have it show on the X Axis?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. Could you upload a screenshot?

Comment: I have added a picture to this

Comment: @SimonBoyle It is on the Y Axis, you probably can't see it because it would appear as a point from that direction.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I have added a screen shot of it from the X Axis. I am wanting this on the Y Axis

Comment: @SimonBoyle Do you want it to have thickness? Or do you want to rotate it (R)?

Comment: I am Learning Blender at the moment (i am wanting it to look as on the x axis but on the y axis)

Answer (score 3):

## Rotating

You can rotate objects with <kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

In the above gif I pressed <kbd>R</kbd> (rotate) <kbd>X</kbd> (axis to rotate on) `90` (degrees to rotate). I then did the same, pressing <kbd>Z</kbd> instead of <kbd>X</kbd> to rotate around the Z axis.

There are several other ways to rotate objects, see [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Basics/Rotate) for more detail.

## Align to view

Note that when you first add an object, there is an option to align it to the view:

[image]

Comment: :) thank you for the help, Very much appreciated